# What are the ports that -F option in nmap probe?

Tags: nmap, port-scanning

I searched the nmap book but I couldn't find the list of ports probed with the -F option. Can anyone help me with this information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the complete list of ports from Nmap by running it in verbose [Grepable output](https://nmap.org/book/output-formats-grepable-output.html) mode without any targets:

```
$ nmap -F -v -oG -
# Nmap 7.70 scan initiated Tue May  7 15:02:23 2019 as: ./nmap -F -v -oG -
# Ports scanned: TCP(100;7,9,13,21-23,25-26,37,53,79-81,88,106,110-111,113,119,135,139,143-144,179,199,389,427,443-445,465,513-515,543-544,548,554,587,631,646,873,990,993,995,1025-1029,1110,1433,1720,1723,1755,1900,2000-2001,2049,2121,2717,3000,3128,3306,3389,3986,4899,5000,5009,5051,5060,5101,5190,5357,5432,5631,5666,5800,5900,6000-6001,6646,7070,8000,8008-8009,8080-8081,8443,8888,9100,9999-10000,32768,49152-49157) UDP(0;) SCTP(0;) PROTOCOLS(0;)
WARNING: No targets were specified, so 0 hosts scanned.
# Nmap done at Tue May  7 15:02:23 2019 -- 0 IP addresses (0 hosts up) scanned in 0.03 seconds
```

Note the line that says "Ports scanned:" which lists 100 TCP ports starting with 7, 9, and 13 and ending with the range 49152-49157.